# Jenkins: Export Build Report

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins for automated deployment.

I want to fetch the reports in excel which have Build name; build number; status of build (success or failure); cause for failure; user who executed this build; date on which the build is executed.

I have used build state plugin. This plugin show the details on Jenkins UI except the cause for failure. Also I don't see any option to export that report in any format.

Can any one please let me know if there is any way to achieve this.